# WIX windows choose folder dialog

Tags: browser, dialog, wix, directory

I would like to know if there is a way how to use windows [choose folder dialog](http://www.addintools.com/documents/infopath/images/browse-for-folder-window.png) instead of really [bad looking one](http://s15.postimg.org/7e9uy9dh7/dialog.png) which is in WIX as a default.

Comment: it is really very good question! you may look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21459111/append-productname-into-installlocation) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4491614/display-files-in-a-directory-list-control)

Answer (score 1):

Beside that you can change the icons used in the default WiX Choose-folder dialog (properties `WixUINewIco` and `WixUIUpIco`), you could:

- either create your own dialog (e.g. check [this tutorial](http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial/user-interface-revisited/customizations-galore))
- or, if you want the Windows dialog shown in the link, you have to create a Custom Action which, on the click on the Browse-button, opens the dialog. You could use e.g. the following VBScript-function for this:

  ```
   ' Function taken from: http://cwashington.netreach.net (that sadly closed)
   ' Author: Jan Herman Scheffer
   Function BrowseForFolder()
        On Error Resume Next
        Dim objShell, objFolder, intColonPos, objWshShell, returnerror
        Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
        Set objWshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        Set objFolder = objShell.BrowseForFolder(&H0, "Select your folder", 514, 17)
        BrowseForFolder = objFolder.ParentFolder.ParseName(objFolder.Title).Path
        returnerror = err.number
        If returnerror <> 0 Then
             If returnerror = 424 then
                  BrowseForFolder = Null
             else
                  intColonPos = InStr(objFolder.Title, ":")
                  If intColonPos > 0 Then
                       BrowseForFolder = Mid(objFolder.Title, intColonPos - 1, 2) & "\"
                       Session.Property("mySelectedFolder") = BrowseForFolder
                  End If
             End If
        End If
   End Function
  ```

With this function you can then assign the selected folder to a property, however you need then another custom action that sets the directory to the selected folder:

```
<CustomAction Id="setFolder" Directory="myFolder" Value="[mySelectedFolder]" />
```

Be sure to schedule this action *after* the `CostFinalize`-action, after all directories are set, or else it won't be set to your value.